# Как поставить язык по умолчанию для всех пользователей (браузеров)

Tags: django, i18n

На сайте есть две рабочие версии перевода - русский и английский используя `i18n`. Как сделать так чтобы у всех сайт загружался на русском языке и потом уже по желанию пользователя он мог поменять его на английский?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Надо сломать автоопределение языка по хидерам

Comment: У вас и так по дефолту русский стоит. Что не так-то?

Comment: @Александр С телефона на английском прогружает сначала

Comment: @SashaBorysenko , скорее всего, это кэш